# Grid inside Stackpanel doesn't stretch

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

The width of the Rectangle is now 0.
if I set the ColumnDefinition to 200 or width in Rectangle tot 200, than I can see the Rectangle. But with the star it's not working.

I'm Trying to set the width of Rectangle 1 and 3 to 40% width and Rectangle 2 to 20%.

What is wrong in my code?

```
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,100,0,0">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Beige" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Red" />
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Beige" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Red" />
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: You have three Rectangles without a width in a Grid without a width. All that in a horizontal StackPanel. What's your expectation?

Comment: A picture of what you are trying to achieve with this layout would help greatly.

Comment: I'm Trying to set the width of Rectangle 1 and 3 to 40% width and Rectangle 2 to 20%;

Comment: Sure, but the whole thing has no width. A horizontal StackPanel aligns its child elements horizontally from left to right according to their "native" width. There is no built-in horizontal stretching.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you need stackpanels at all? You could do with just grids.

Anyway, StackPanel doesn't stretch along its orientation (i.e. vertical stackpanel does not stretch vertically and horizontal stackpanel does not stretch horizontally).

Example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="0,100,0,0"
        Background="Aquamarine"
        >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Height="200" Fill="Beige" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Red" />
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Height="200"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="2" Height="200" Fill="Beige" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Red" />

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Note: you don't need `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` for rectangles -- thay are stretching by default. And specifying `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` along with `Height="200"` doesn't make sense anyway.

**Update:** And the problem in your inital code is here:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" ... >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ...>
        <Grid>
```

Grid tries to occupy all available space. What space is available? You have two nested stackpanels: one doesn't stretch vertically and another doesn't stretch horizontally. So, the grid with no `Height` or `Width` specified has zero space available. If you remove `Height="200"` from rectangles, you may see that your grid is zero-sized.