# WPF Listbox stretching issues

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have created a UserControl that is suppose to display some text and then present a listbox for the user to select some item.

It is supposed to strech to the height to the grid cell it is placed in. And if there are more items than can fit on screen then to display a vertical scrollbar. After much trial and error I have finally managed to get it working as expected. But only when the row height is a pixel value. If I use any partial (by partial I mean the star symbol), the grid cell's height is not contained. Since I need the app the match screen size I need the partials to work.

Putting 100 items in the listbox suddenly makes the height of the entire grid is around 11000 (which I think is everything with no contraint). Meaning there is no scrollbar. See [Screenshot] https://i.stack.imgur.com/faES9.png.

I have a similar issue with my TextBox only horizontally. It will only activate when clicking on a specific pixel since it is empty the width is only 1 pixel. I hope someone can help me point out where I am going wrong, cause since I'm having more than one issue I suspect the problem is on my end.

This is my XAML code.

```
<UserControl x:Class="PackingStation.UserControls.SearchItemListing"
             x:Name="SearchItemListingRoot"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PackingStation.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="1000" d:DesignWidth="1000">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=SearchItemListingRoot}"
          x:Name="TheGrid"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height=".1*" />
                  <RowDefinition Height=".1*" />

        <!-- If this value isnt a pixel value it will not vertically strech to available space -->
                  <RowDefinition Height="*" />
           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="0,0,0,0"
                       x:Name="TheHeadLineField"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="1">
                 <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyleHeadline32}" 
                        Content="{Binding Title}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>  
                 <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelStyleText}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Content="{Binding SubTitle}"
                        FontSize="20"/>
            </StackPanel>
            
            <!-- Search Field -->
            <Border Style="{StaticResource Border6}"
                    x:Name="TheSearchField"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Background="{StaticResource ColorSummaryPanelBackground}"
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource ColorSummaryPanelBorder}"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    Margin="0,40,0,0">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Height="78"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Image Stretch="Uniform"
                           Height="24"
                           Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfUI;component/Icons/Search.png"
                           Margin="36,0,0,0"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    
                    <!-- Search Textbox -->
                    <!-- Similar issue with this textbox, only horizontally. With no content you have to hit a specific pixel to activate it -->
                    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxSearchInlay}"
                             Name="TbxSearchTerm"
                             TextChanged="TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged"
                             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                             Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            
            <!-- Search results listings -->
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                     x:Name="TheListBox"
                     Grid.Row="2"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                     VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                          <DataTemplate>
                                 <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,-10,0,-10">
                                        <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelSearchItem}"
                                               Content="{Binding Name}"
                                               HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                 </StackPanel>
                          </DataTemplate>
                   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could repro your problem when I put your `UserControl` in a `StackPanel`. When it's in a `Grid` the `ListBox` shows its vertical scrollbar. So, try your `UserControl` in a `Grid`.

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34856380/2411960) will give a good explanation about `Grid` and `StackPanel` stretching behavior.

Comment: I put the usercontrol in a Grid and now it works. Thank you Andrew, I truly appreciate the input.